# Unable to use ColorWheel without loading kv (AttributeError)

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

Can't understand why I get
`AttributeError: 'ColorWheel' object has no attribute 'sv_s'`
When I run

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.colorpicker import ColorWheel
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        box = BoxLayout()
        box.add_widget(ColorWheel())
        self.root = box

MainApp().run()
```

and I haven't any errors when use kv, for example:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
KV = '''
BoxLayout
    ColorWheel
'''

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_string(KV)

MainApp().run()
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 2):

You missed the warning in the [`ColorPicker` documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.colorpicker.html?highlight=colorwheel#module-kivy.uix.colorpicker). That is a bug in the `ColorWheel` code. You should report it as a bug at [Kivy Issues](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues).